# Using sql within shell script

Tags: sql, shell

I am currently trying to integrate an sql statement into a shell script, But facing major syntax issue:

My statement in the script:

```
su - <sid>adm -c 'hdbsql -U SYSTEM export "'SCHEMA'"."'*'" as binary into "'Export Location'" with reconfigure'
```

I get the following error:

```
* 257: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "*": line 1 col 16 (at pos 16) SQLSTATE: HY000
```

Would really appreciate if anyone could help me with this.

Thanks and Regards,
AK

Answer (score 0):

Your command line doesn't make much sense to me. It starts with

```
su - <sid>adm
```

which means that you are redirecting the contents of the file "sid" into "su" and then redirecting the result of that operation into the file "adm".

Second problem is that in the command you are giving to adm, the single quotes end right before the "*" which means, that the "*" will get interpreted by the shell as a file glob:

```
-c 'hdbsql -U SYSTEM export "'SCHEMA'"."'*'" as binary into "'Export Location'" with reconfigure'
```

You'll need to escape those single quotes like this: "\'".

But I think your problem solving approach is not good. Try to reduce to problem and only then start adding additional things to it. So first try to execute the SQL statement from the "hdbsql" shell. Does it work?

```
$ hdbsql
> YOUR SQL STATEMENT HERE
```

Once that works, try to execute the SQL statement from the unix shell as a user:

```
$ hdbsql -U SYSTEM export ...
```

Once that works, try to execute it via su

```
$ su - ...
```

Comment: Hi Tomas, Kindly ignore the "<>" . SID is the system id